# Can I include the categories of things I am counting as a predictor variable in a poisson GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data

I am wanting to do a GLM on some count data where I have 31 samples from two groups in which items of interest has been identified. I am then looking for 4 different markers on the items and counting across a sample how many times I see each marker. My goal of the GLM is to see if there is a difference in the counts of these markers between each group.

I plan to do this by comparing the residual deviances between a model with the `group` term and one dropping it. However, is it reasonable to include the maker categories as a predictor variable also?:

```
count ~ group + maker_category
count ~ maker_category
```

My logic for doing this would be to allow for the potential that differences in counts between marker types could just be because that marker type is more frequently seen always.

Would it also be worth including the item of interest itself in the model as the same item can be (but is not always) found in both groups? Such that:

```
count ~ group + maker_category + item
count ~ maker_category + item
```

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to ensure I provided context.

Comment: Your verbal data description needs to be augmented with a sample of the actual data.

Comment: Some of your formulas have two `~`, that makes no sense. Please edit!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Fixed, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I still see one formula with two ~'s ...